# Can we add post commands with the salt network module?

Tags: networking, interface, saltstack

I'd like to add `post-up` and `post-down` commands to my network interfaces. Can [salt.states.network](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.network.html) do that ?

If not what would be the best way to add them using salt knowing that I can't simply add them at the end of the file since there is other interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian is nice in using `.d` run-parts directories.

Just put a script in `/etc/network/if-post-up.d/` and `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` and you're done.

For example:

```
add_route_up_script:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/network/if-up.d/my-route
    - mode: 0755
    - source: salt://network/if-up-route
```

See interfaces(5) for available environment variables like `IFACE`, `METHOD`, etc. These are the same as in `interfaces` file.